# Как загрузить сайт на хостинг через FTP?

Tags: django

В общем возникла такая пироблема с переносом файлов на хостинг Timeweb. Проблема в том что когда весь проект импортировался и даже база данных стоит, мне выбивает ошибку 403. Как я понял дело в сайте а именно в его построении так как построен он по документации. И вот как выглядит построение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

где Homepage это приложение а media корневая папка для изображений
Что как импортировать я не в курсе так как у других построение сайта не похоже на то что у меня

Comment: А что за тип "хостинга"  у вас там? Web hosting, VPS, VDS?

Comment: @void Прлблема в том что я не знаю как посмотреть, на главной странице где пишет статус сервера там web но даже не знаю то ли это

Comment: Вам теорию учить ещё и учить с таким уровнем. Я подозреваю, вы пытаетесь на обычном хостинге типа PHP/MySQL запустить приложение Python. Так не делается и работать не будет от слова совсем.

Comment: @void Да, признаю, но хотя бы скиньте материалы, или покажите как делается

Comment: Нет ничего такого универсального на свете, чтобы почитать, поверьте. Учеба, практика, понимание что как работает и чем что отличается - именно этого надо достичь, а книжки универсальной не существует. Ищите принципы CGI, работы и конфигураций веб-серверов, динамических сайтов. технологий.